# Java regex logical number of matched characters

Tags: java, regex, unicode

Let's say I need to match a string containing characters that don't fit 16 bits and are handled by the high-low surrogate pairs in Java. For example the [pizza slice](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F355/index.htm) character.

I've written the following code to match it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\uD83C\uDF55");
String s = "\uD83C\uDF55";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.end());
```

What surprises me is that the output is 2 instead of 1, as there is logically one character. Is there a way to tell Java regex matcher to return 1 here?

Comment: Why is there a pizza slice character?

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? I need to deal with characters that don't fit 16 bits. That's an example.

Comment: I was making a joke.

Comment: Then a &#127829; for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A `String` object uses a `char[]` as a backing structure. Most `String` methods operate with the `char` values in that array. `Matcher` does the same. It reports where the matched pattern starts and ends in respect to that underlying `char[]`.

Comment: That really sucks, but appears to be the case! I need to hack around myself

Comment: @Ali Can you explain what you're trying to do with the logical character? Is it for logging or display? You'll need the `char` index if you're going to manipulate the `String`.

Comment: I'm writing a parser that needs to parse arbitrary unicode input. There are two problems with the way Java handles unicode. First, I need to always check if charAt(i) is a BPM or high surrogate char which is annoying. I converted the input into a char array, and treated everything UTF 32, but then I lose the interpretability with Java regex library. I think I will do some hacks to get the logical character number. Any regex library that works on an int array?

Comment: @Ali I don't know of any. I'm assuming you're using `String` methods that operate on code points.

Comment: Actually static methods on `Character` that provide code point operations.